# Time series linearity test

Tags: python, time-series

Is there a test in python which allows to know if a time series is linear or not?
I want to know which module of kalman filter I have to use in order to correct my forecast data.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to do a "linear regression". [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) are Python math libraries that can help.

Here's an [example](http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/03/linear-regression-with-numpy.html) of a linear regression using Numpy and SciPy:

```
from numpy import arange
from pylab import plot,show
from scipy import stats

xi = arange(0,9)
# linearly generated sequence
y = [19, 20, 20.5, 21.5, 22, 23, 23, 25.5, 24]

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xi,y)

print 'r-value', r_value
print 'p-value', p_value
print 'standard deviation', std_err

line = slope*xi + intercept
plot(xi,line,'r-',xi,y,'o')
show()
```

The closer your [`r-value`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) is to 1, the more closely your data matches then calculated line. Since the linear regression produces a line, and the `r-value` tell you how your data fits the line, an `r-value` of 1 would mean your series is completely linear.

Comment: How can I apply this to time series? I don't get it!
Can you give me a reference in order to use it in my paper
I think that what ou did is an Augmented Dickey Fuller test!
Please, give me a reference for the assesment the closer is the r-value to 1 the more we have a linear ts

Comment: Can we say below one threshold of r-value, the time series is linear?
For example, a test inducing that if r-value is above 0.5 for example we have a linear time series

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [statsmodels.tsa](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/index.html) and try an ARMA (auto regressive moving average) model. Specifically the kalman filter methods can be found [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.kalmanf.kalmanfilter.KalmanFilter.html?highlight=kalman%20filter#statsmodels.tsa.kalmanf.kalmanfilter.KalmanFilter).

Comment: I have read on a forum a message posted by @jseabold that this was not what would allow me to implement a forecast correction(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pystatsmodels/0hx7QBlSBiY).
And that for general implementation pykalman had to be used?
Have you ever used any of this libraries (either Kalman Filter in Statsmodels or pykalman?)